# Is there any gain using else statement?

Tags: python

Is there any difference in using if-else like this:

```
def foo:
  if bar:
    return baz
  else:
    return False
```

or like this:

```
def foo:
  if bar:
    return baz
  return False
```

?

Comment: No there is no difference, you can only return once

Comment: PEP-8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) includes both ways, with the limitation that all code paths must return a value.

Comment: One or the other *might* be more readable/clearer. Perhaps `return baz if bar else False` would be even clearer in terms of having only one `return` statement... it depends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, both code snippets will accomplish exactly the same thing.

The only advantage of the else-statement is the code readability, so other people can easier understand what you did there when looking at your code.

Comment: thanks, I will re-paste PEP-8 reference from @SBI so it will be easier to find in future: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Both program will have the exact same behavior. But, the point will be to consider which one is the best for the sake of clarity while having a code reading session.

I would tend to prefer the `else` program because it makes it instantaneously clear that the output of the procedure will be either `baz` or `False`.